# Jquery window set width

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
    checkWindowSize();

    function checkWindowSize() {

        var elWidth  = $("#elId").outerWidth(),
            elHeight = $("#elId").outerHeight();


        $(window).innerWidth(elWidth);
        $(window).innerHeight(elHeight);
    }
});
```

I want to resize browser window every time when I call checkWindowSize() function. But I've noticed that resize functions for window object don't work.
How I can resize browser window?

Comment: You can only resize a window that was created dynamically with `window.open()`. And you can't resize a window with multiple tabs open. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo

Comment: This is my case: the window opened by window.open. But then I have to resize it depends on content.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer

My new function:

```
function checkWindowSize() {

    var elWidth  = $("#elId").outerWidth(),
        elHeight = $("#elId']").outerHeight(),

        browserElements = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;

    window.resizeTo(elWidth, elHeight + browserElements);

}
```